# How to center a background div?

Tags: html, css

**What I want**

two div : A *page body* (1) and a *background block* (2)

- *background block* is always (2560 x 780) px
- *page body* width is 820px while height is variable
- *background block* should be behind *page body*
- *background block* and *page body* should both be centered
- *background block* should not move relatively to *page body* when resizing the window (even by 1 pixel !)
- no horizontal scroll bar should appear for *background block*
- *background block* position isn't fixed

[image: Desired layout]

**Constraints**

- no JS
- CSS2 preferred

**What I tried**

Page body CSS:

```
#pageBody {
    width: 820px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Background block CSS:

**1. A full-page div which displays a CSS centered background**

```
<div id="backgroundBlock"></div>
<div id="pageBody">
</div>
```

```
#backgroundBlock {
    background: no-repeat center 0 url(bg.png);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

But when the window's size is odd:

- the CSS background is shifted by 1 pixel on the left
- background image appears blurry on Internet Explorer

**2. A repositioned child div**

- make *background block* a child of *page body* (which is centered)
- make *background block* positioned absolute (to put it behind *page body*)
- use negative margins to reposition the *background block*
- make *background block* overflow: hidden to prevent the scroll bar from appear for that div

```
<div id="pageBody">
    <div id="backgroundBlock"></div>
</div>
```

```
#backgroundBlock {
    background: no-repeat url(bg.png);
    width: 2560px;
    height: 780px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 0 0 -870px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

But problem: the scroll bar appears for the *background block*...

Comment: Please show your HTML

Comment: Is the background block going to be like a full width full page background with fixed position?

Comment: No, the background isn't fixed. I forgot that point.

Comment: Sorry another question: is the background image size always going to be 2560 X 780 in px values?

Comment: Yes, always 2560 x 780. Added in the question.

Comment: The problem I am encountering is centering the background right in the middle with the overflow on the left and right to be hidden yet the user can scroll left or right? I was able to center the pageBody right smack in the center (obviously)

Comment: I am assuming the key is the overflow on the both sides of the background, correct?

Comment: "... yet the user can'T scroll left or right?", you mean can't, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74292/discussion-between-user1746515-and-sai).

Comment: I would make the background a separate element. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/emoEyR

Comment: @Shikkediel It looks great but when I try to integrate it on my website, the background block is displayed after a 100% height (I need to scroll to see it)

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wBZqxa  now in tht example ( thanks to @Shikkediel ) do you want the scroll for the horizontal axis?

Comment: Not sure what's causing that, @user1746515. I did some minor changes in the meantime that might make a difference. Could you share a live link otherwise?

Comment: Okay, the problem was the background-image on the html element... I don't know why...

Comment: Oops, there's still a little problem: when the page's width is lesser than than 820px (the page body), the background block is still centered while it should match the position of the page body... :/

Comment: If I understand it correctly, centering page body 'oldskool' as well should help. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEwXGQ

Comment: Yes, that's it! Thank you!
But now I realize we fell into the same problem I got with the CSS centered background when the window's width isn't even :
the background image of the background block is blurred on IE and shifted on chrome

Comment: I'm afraid I can't replicate those issues (both browsers look normal to me) so I wouldn't know of an answer. No clues to be found on google either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas I could think of, with their issues. However, I could not reproduce the "blurry in IE" issue, so I don't know which solution have it or not.
I did put "Extra markup" as an issue for solutions including a `div` (`#backgroundBlock`) only used to display the background image, as it is not semantic.

---

#### Solution 1 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gfLr6n3e/))

- **Description** : Your first solution
- **Issues** :

  - Extra markup
  - On Chrome, depending on the page size, pixels can be aligned differently. You can see it on jsfiddle near the right border : [image: pixel problem]

---

#### Solution 2 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uoob677m/))

- **Description** : Multiple-backgrounds on body. `#backgroundBlock` div not needed.

  ```css
  body {
      background: no-repeat center top url(bg.png), url(bodybg.png);
  }
  ```
- **Issues** :

  - Not compatible with old browsers (IE8, FF3.5, ... ; [source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds))
  - On Chrome, same alignment problem as in *solution 1*

---

#### Solution 3 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnfg1ro3/))

- **Description** : Use of `translate`. No more pixel alignment errors.

  ```css
  #backgroundBlock
  {
      background: url(bg.png);
      width: 2560px;
      height: 780px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  ```
- **Issues** :

  - Extra markup
  - You have to use `overflow-x: hidden` on `body` to avoid horizontal scrollbar
  - Not compatible with old browsers (IE8, FF3, ... ; [source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)). You should also use prefixes for compatibility (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, ...). I did not add them to keep the example simple

---

#### Solution 4 ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qdyn5qnf/))

- **Description** : Use of `translate` and `::before`. Alternative version of *solution 3*. Pseudo-elements compatibility are not an issue here since every browser supporting 2D-tranforms supports `::before` ([source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent)).

  ```css
  #backgroundBlock
  {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: hidden;
  }
  #backgroundBlock:before
  {
      content: '';
      background: url(bg.png);
      width: 2560px;
      height: 780px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  }
  ```
- **Issues** :

  - Extra markup
  - Not compatible with old browsers (IE8, FF3, ... ; [source](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms2d)). You should also use prefixes for compatibility (`-webkit-`, `-moz-`, ...). I did not add them to keep the example simple

---

There are other possibilities but I think most of them would have one of the above issues.
For example, you could set the `#pageBody` width to 2560px, set the background on it, add padding to have a content size of 820px and `translate` it in order to have it centered on the page (and prevent horizontal scrollbars using `overflow-x` on `body`). This would be possible because the background image and page body both have fixed width.